# Sql Server sync alternatives

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, microsoft-sync-framework

We have two Sql 2008 R2 database. First and main one is on-premise which is used by our stock management and accounting systems.
The second is for our web site and it is on a 3th party hosting firm and that database is updated manually by a standard XML file operation
(creating XML from on-premise database, sending it to web server, reading from XML file & insert/update/delete web database)

we need to get rid of that manual XML operation and sync that two databases automatically, but problem is our hosting firm does not allow "Replication" or "Linked Server" facilities on their "Sql Server" system. That's way we can not sync databases with these "Sql Server" facilities.

I am trying find out sync alternatives for that scenario without changing the hosting system.

What options can we use ?

Is Microsoft Sync Framework can be used for this scenario? ( I'm not sure if it is just for the Microsoft Azure Sql system)

Thanks…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're fine coding, then Sync Framework can do this.

Sync Framework can sync SQL Compact, Express, Server, Azure or LocalDB

But bear in mind that Sync Framework will need to create some Sync-related objects on your databases (triggers, stored procedures, tables, etc...)

Comment: does Sync Framework need new objects on both databases ? changing on-premise database not possible in the short term, but we can play with hosting(web site) db.

Comment: both sides...it needs to track changes and it does it via triggers updating  tracking tables. it applies changes using stored procs as well.

Comment: @JuneT do you think sync framework is still the only way , it is not updated from years,what is the best way now.

Comment: @Dragon - what are you trying to sync?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a hosting provider that provides these services.

It is typical for a hosting provider to provide an on-demand or always VPN connection to the production servers from the client location to the servers at the hosting location.  Such a service is often needed for support of online systems.  If you had such a connection then having SQL Server do syncs would be no problem.

Any major (Rack Space, Peer1, etc) provider would be able to set up such a system.

It probably won't be as inexpensive as your current provider.

Comment: thanks.. but as i said management doesn't want to change hosting provider in the short term.

Comment: @AdamRight - You might also consider the Red Gate tools -- they are quite good and can be automated.

Answer (score 0):

Well if changing a provider is not an option, at list in the short term and you need something right now, you can always automate parts or all your current process.

For that you can at least use:

- PowerShell (or even plain old cmd.exe) script(batch) and bcp.exe to export and import your files on both ends and PowerShell and ftp to transfer your files from one server to another.
- SQLServer Integration Services on premises to export and send files via ftp to your hosting location. And SSIS to grab and import those files at your hosting location.